# Python / Tensorflow / Numpy setting an array element with a sequence error

Tags: python, numpy, tensorflow, neural-network

I'm experimenting with the Generative Adversarial Network found here:
https://github.com/carpedm20/DCGAN-tensorflow
I've installed all the prereqs and downloaded the code and I've hit an error that I'm not sure where it's coming from. After running main.py with any image set, I get the following error:

```
ValueError: setting an array element with a sequence
```

The line it mentions, line 153 of model.py, is as follows:

```
sample_images = np.array(sample).astype(np.float32)
```

'sample_images' seems to be set to a tensorflow placeholder, based on lines 75  and 76 of model.py:

```
self.sample_images= tf.placeholder(tf.float32, [self.sample_size] + [self.output_size, self.output_size, self.c_dim],
                                    name='sample_images')
```

Some googling has led me towards using something like 'feed_dict', but a few experiments with this haven't worked. Additionally feed_dict is used later on in the code, like this at line 187:

```
feed_dict={ self.images: batch_images, self.z: batch_z, self.y:batch_labels })
```

I'm not sure if this is Python, Tensorflow, Numpy or something else causing the error so don't really know where to start. Help appreciated.

For reference, I'm running Python 3.5 64-bit on Windows 7

Thanks

Nathan

UPDATE: After far too long spent trying to fix this, I eventually spun up an Ubuntu VM, installed Python and Tensorflow and the whole thing works without a hitch. Not quite an answer to the original question, but definitely a workaround.

Answer (score -1):

I don't have `tensorflow`, so can't help you directly.  But I can create your error with something similar

Make an dtype object array with lists of various sizes:

```
In [343]: x=np.array([3, [1,2], [1,2,3]],dtype=object)
In [344]: x
Out[344]: array([3, [1, 2], [1, 2, 3]], dtype=object)
In [345]: x.astype(np.float32)
...
ValueError: setting an array element with a sequence.
```

The same would apply if one or more of the elements were an array, and I imagine a `tensorflow` object, if iterable (as sequence), would produce the same error.

So - check the `dtype` of `sample_images`, and identify the type of the elements.  Also check the `tensorflow` has its own methods of converting its objects to arrays of floats.  Don't assume that `numpy` functions and methods work directly on `tensorflow` objects.